# Why is it that JProgressBar should not be changed once added to a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, components, jprogressbar

**Straight and Simple:** *Imagine we're on a class that extends JPanel*

```
JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0,0,10);
add(bar);

bar.setValue(5); //Works - You can visually see the change
bar = new JProgressBar(0,0,10);
bar.setValue(10); //Works - You can NOT visually see the change
```

**Why's that?**

And no, I couldn't find it anywhere that I looked. I searched for this specific question far and wide.

Comment: *"I searched for this specific question far and wide."* It's the same with any component & setting the original variable to point to it. Instantiating a new component is not the same as actually adding that component on screen and making it visible. But then, what is the purpose of doing what you seem to be trying to do?

Comment: It is assumed/suggested that you do your own research and look far and wide, so saying as much does not need to be part of the question. It does not help. Perhaps you could be more specific in your actual question. If someone else were asking you this question, how would they word it in a way that you best understood what they are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java variables act (in effect) like pointers.

You create a `JProgressBar` and add it to your `JPanel` - and store *a pointer* to this in the variable `bar`.  When you call `bar = new JProgressBar(0, 0, 10);` you change what your pointer is pointing to, but do *not* change the original `JProgressBar` (the one which was added to your `JPanel`), you now have a *new*, different `JProgressBar` (which is *not* added to your `JPanel`), and so setting the value on it does not modify the one which *is* visible on your `JPanel`.

This is the same reason that:

```
String name = "Billy";
String otherName = name;
name = "Jimmy";
System.out.println(otherName);
```

will print `Billy`.

Comment: Thank you, clarified. I know that about pointers, but I thought components added would store the component, so if it points to a different thing, the same happens to the one in the componentPane.